# remove specific pattern from a file

Tags: python

I have string of the form

```
    HELLO SET("ui_mapping_text"='#cast( 
    #sum(cast(STG_HO.TOTAL_ORDER,\'decimal(8,0)\')-cast(STG_HO.TAX,\'decimal(8,0)\'))/100
    #+
    #sum(cast(STG_HO.TOTAL_DISCOUNT,\'decimal(8,0)\'))/100
    #+ 
    #sum(cast(STG_HO.GST_DISCOUNT,\'decimal(8,0)\'))/100, \'decimal(10,2)\')
    cast(
    sum(cast(STG_HO.TOTAL_ORDER,\'decimal(8,0)\')-cast(STG_HO.TAX,\'decimal(8,0)\'))/100
    +
    sum(cast(STG_HO.TOTAL_DISCOUNT,\'decimal(8,0)\'))/100
    + 
    sum(cast(nvl(STG_HO.GST_DISCOUNT,0),\'decimal(8,0)\'))/100, \'decimal(10,2)\')')

HELLO
```

I want to remove whatever is in between the SET() and SET itself from a file  in python . prenthesis matching is required.

Expected output

```
HELLO
HELLO
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use regex for this.

```
txt = r"""
HELLO SET("ui_mapping_text"='#cast( 
    #sum(cast(STG_HO.TOTAL_ORDER,\'decimal(8,0)\')-cast(STG_HO.TAX,\'decimal(8,0)\'))/100
    #+
    #sum(cast(STG_HO.TOTAL_DISCOUNT,\'decimal(8,0)\'))/100
    #+ 
    #sum(cast(STG_HO.GST_DISCOUNT,\'decimal(8,0)\'))/100, \'decimal(10,2)\')
    cast(
    sum(cast(STG_HO.TOTAL_ORDER,\'decimal(8,0)\')-cast(STG_HO.TAX,\'decimal(8,0)\'))/100
    +
    sum(cast(STG_HO.TOTAL_DISCOUNT,\'decimal(8,0)\'))/100
    + 
    sum(cast(nvl(STG_HO.GST_DISCOUNT,0),\'decimal(8,0)\'))/100, \'decimal(10,2)\')')
HELLO
"""

import re

result = re.sub(r"SET\((?s).*\)","",txt)

print (result)
```

Result:

```
HELLO 
HELLO
```

Comment: Does not do the ( matching . will remove the ones after SET() has benn closed

Comment: It runs exactly as shown above with your data. If you have other requirements, you should update your question.

Comment: have already mentioned that parenthsis matching is required in the original question. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

One idea is that you can create a variable `nested` = 0. When it first encounter `SET(`, you increment `nested` by 1. Next, whenever there is a `(` you increment it by one and decrements by 1 when there is an ')'. By the time `nested == 0`, you know that ')' is the one that close the `SET(`

To achieve the purpose of outputting, you only output when `nested` equals to `0`. When `nested > 0`, it means it is inside a `SET(...)`